# 502 bad gateway after upgrading PHP5-FPM

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, 502

I just upgraded php-fpm and my server has gone away with a `502 bad gateway` I've been searching for solutions and came across some like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10470827/1612432

and this

[Getting 502 bad gateway after updating php to 5.5](https://serverfault.com/questions/585465/getting-502-bad-gateway-after-updating-php-to-5-5)

But with no luck. 
I've changed `fastcgi_pass` from a unix socket to `127.0.0.1:9000` and in the php pool `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`. But I keep getting the `502`

Here are my config files:

In the nginx config:

```
upstream php {
       #server unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
       server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

And later on my site config I have:

```
fastcgi_pass php;
```

In my php pool:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Some error logs from nginx log

```
 2015/03/23 10:38:48 [error] 14365#0: *485 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 66.249.78.19, server: elbauldelprogramador.com, request: "GET /tag/configurar-prefetch-windows-8/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "elbauldelprogramador.com"
```

I've also noticed this warning in php logs:

```
[23-Mar-2015 12:38:59] WARNING: [pool www] child 33877 exited with code 127 after 5.620225 seconds from start
```

After searching a bit more, it seems that the problem is in swaping php workers, I do not know what means the error code 127, but when the server was running it always was 0.

If you need more config files, please tell me.

Comment: 502 could be an error in php, or php-fpm is not running

Comment: Yes, it is, but I can not solve it.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18465550/648159) useful?

Comment: I've solved the problem, it was apc. I will post the answer in two days

Comment: No.. because stackexange does not allow me to anser my own question until 2 days pass

Comment: Mmmm, I can, maybe this restriction is only on StackOverflow. sorry.

Comment: Sorry!, the restriction is for “acepting” the answer, not for posting it. sorry for the misunderstanding,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the root cause of the problem. After the php update, the apc extension I have in my `php.ini` was no longer working, all its all right now after commenting this line:

```
extension=apc.so
```

Hope it helps.